unknown popup after use combo keys: "option + return"
I use "Simple Text" Input source for using Vietnamese language.
typing a word then press Option + Return keys make popup appears and replace the word. I wonder what is it and How to turn it off?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
